# What does the "eye" symbol mean at the bottom of Telegram messages?

Tags: telegram

In Telegram Messenger, at the bottom of each message, there are two numbers. One is the time that the message has been sent, and the other is a number near an eye symbol. Does anyone know what this number means?

Note that this number is in all messages, not only messages released in groups or channels.
These are two screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess it indicates total views of the post.

Comment: Do you mean all telegram users who view the post?

Comment: I do not know how Telegram works, but the eye icon is typically used to show the total view count i.e. total number of times the original post (be it image, article or whatever) has been loaded or seen by users. E.g., Quora uses a similar icon to show post views. See image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VpI3Q.png

Answer (score 7):

As per Telegram's [official blog](https://telegram.org/blog):

> Each post in a channel has its own view counter.
>
> [image]
>
> Views from forwarded copies of your messages will be included in the total count.

That eye icon is usually used to depict the total page or post views. For example, Quora uses a [similar icon](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-Telegram-app-not-as-popular-as-WhatsApp-when-its-way-better-than-WhatsApp):

[image]

You can find some more icons [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=page+OR+post+view+icon&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CBwQsARqFQoTCJDsloT1mskCFUwYjgodIjAA9w).